# aggregate rows with condition in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

My example

```
df <- data.frame(id1 = c("a" , "b", "c"),
                 id2 = c("a", "a", "d"),
                 n1 = c(2,2,0),
                 n2 = c(2,1,1),
                 n3 = c(0,1,1),
                 n4 = c(0,1,1))
```

First, I already aggregated all rows across column like this

```
df <- df %>%
group_by(id2) %>% 
summarise(across(c(n1,n2,n3,n4), sum, na.rm = TRUE), 
            .groups = "drop")
```

Now, but now I would like to aggregate only 2 first rows having `a` in column `id2`. How we keep the column `id1` since my desire output like this. Honestly, that column is just used to compare to `id2` and is quite redundant, but I really want to keep it.

```
id1 id2 n1 n2 n3 n4 
a   a   4  3  1  1
c   d   0  1  1  1
```

Any suggestions for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `id2` values where it has `'a'` in it.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id1 = ifelse(id2 == 'a', id2, id1), id2) %>% 
  summarise(across(starts_with('n'), sum, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = "drop")

#  id1   id2      n1    n2    n3    n4
#  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 a     a         4     3     1     1
#2 c     d         0     1     1     1
```

Comment: thank you so much. However, what if we have so many cases having the same characters like that.

Comment: We can change multiple values with `%in%` i.e `ifelse(id2 %in% c('a', 'b', 'c'), id2, id1)`. You may also change the value to `a` directly instead of `id2` i.e `id1 = ifelse(id2 %in% c('a', 'b', 'c'), 'a', id1)`

Answer (score 2):

Other solution would be using `case_when`. This function is more readable if you need to use multiple casuistic sentences:

```r
library(dplyr)
   df %>%
      mutate(id1 = case_when(
        id2 == 'a' ~ id2,
        TRUE ~ id1
      )) %>% 
      group_by(id1, id2) %>% 
      summarise(across(starts_with('n'), sum, na.rm = TRUE), 
                .groups = "drop")
```

which yields:

```r
## A tibble: 2 x 6
#  id1   id2      n1    n2    n3    n4
#  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 a     a         4     3     1     1
#2 c     d         0     1     1     1
```

> **Note**: The `summarise` part was copied from [@Ronak Shah's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69204812/8676170)